# How to use reveal view controller in the middle of the project rather than initial view controller

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I am using revealviewcontroller in swift. After successful login, my control should go to reveal view controller.but when I move to reveal view controller, my menubarbutton is not working.

```
let svc :SWRevealViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("reveal") as! SWRevealViewController

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: svc)

self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: can you show your storyboard scene

Comment: simple we can access in two ways

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573338/swrevealviewcontroller-button-not-work-after-clicking-back-button-from-another-v?noredirect=1#comment72331011_42573338 hello @Anbu.Karthik can you please look a view my problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In App delegate

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

 @UIApplicationMain
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { 
 .....
 }

 fun rootVC()
 {
  let svc :SWRevealViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("reveal") as! SWRevealViewController
  let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: svc)
  self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Set Initialise VC is LoginVC... After Login and Enter Secure PIN... On Click On Submit Call rootVC as below

```
func SubmitAction(sender : UIButton)
{
 appDelegate.rootVC()
}
```

Not required to create object of app delegate in any view controller...

I hope you understand..

Thanks

Comment: thanks both. @karthick. I could navigate to the account view after clicking submit button. But still the menu button is not working ....   if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuIcon.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuIcon.action = "revealToggle:"
           menuIcon.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }

Comment: Finally found the solution, made the reveal view controller as the root view controller and declared it in app delegate and called it on submit click action. Thank you all for your quick responses.

Comment: Hello bro @MemonIrshad, could you please help and check my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573338/swrevealviewcontroller-button-not-work-after-clicking-back-button-from-another-v?noredirect=1#comment72408455_42573338     ??